# SQL Query to convert grid result to csv file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, smscaster

I am using SMS caster to send sms.It has an option to Import csv files.

Now I want to dynamically create csv file of CellNo column of Person table from Visual Studio 2010 connected SQL Server 2008.So that I click on a button and it creates a csv file which I can then access from my software SMSCaster to send sms.

The solutions available are either manual-based or if some query is provided it requires Microsoft OLEDB.....so is there any simple query to convert queryresult into .csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Namespace : System.IO;

```
        var _lines = new List<string>();
        for(int _i=0;i<gridview1.rows.count;_i++)
        {
            string[] _mobileNos = gridView1.rows[_i].cells[mobilecolumn index in gridview].text;
            var header = string.Join(",", _mobileNos);
            _lines.Add(header);
        }
        File.WriteAllLines("FileName.csv",_lines);
```

Comment: @Muhammad Suleman example : if your mobile no is in 3rd column.. use gridView1.rows[_i].cells[3].text

Comment: One thing remaining..."gvCellNo.Rows[_i].Cells[0].Value"....gives an error, "cannot convert object type to string[]"....also "gvCellNo.Rows[_i].Cells[0].Text" too doesn't work.

Comment: public void gridtoCSV()
        {
            var _lines = new List<string>();
            for (int _i = 0; _i < gvCellNo.Rows.Count; _i++)
            {
                string[] _mobileNos = gvCellNo.Rows[_i].Cells[0].Value;
                var header = string.Join(",", _mobileNos);
                _lines.Add(header);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines("FileName.csv", _lines);
        }

Comment: @Mohammad Suleman .. string[] _mobileNos ;

In for loop _mobileNos[_i]=gvCellNo.Rows[_i].Cells[0].Value

Comment: what is myvalue and ing

Comment: So @Revanayya Hiremath...finally this code worked


public void gridtoCSVFILE()
        {
            string ing;
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < gvCellNo.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                
                ing = gvCellNo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                lines.Add(ing);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines("FileName.csv", lines);
        }


Thanks very very much mate...One thing more...I want to replace old .csv file with old one each time it is created...any suggestion??

Comment: @Muhammad Suleman Check the existence of file like if(File.exists("Filepath"))

Comment: ....After creating setup...the respective csv file that is made in bin folder before setup is not made.Can u help?Bcz after Installer Setup there is only Release and Debug folder

Comment: @Muhammad Suleman Can I put one more answer or shall i comment here ?

Comment: ver very sorry..I actually don't know where to click..plz tell me...I "ll first do it...rest afterwards...I tried to voteup several times..but it says I require 15 reputations for this

Comment: Done mate...So csv file after setup

Comment: Before creating the setup.. instead of build.. make it as Release and build application and make setup

Comment: could u plz tell me how to make it as Release,as u told...bcz csv file is not being made.

Comment: Yes sure..Use File.WriteAllLines("PathName\FileName.csv",_lines); or infront of Run button select Release from dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked:

public void gridtoCSVFILE()

```
    {
        string ing;
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < gvStudCellNo.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ing = gvStudCellNo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            lines.Add(ing);
            File.WriteAllLines("StudentsCellNo.csv", lines);
        }
    }
```

//it will create csv file in your bin folder...also it automatically replaces each new file with the old one